# Remembering a User Preference with a Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to present users with 2 options upon entering a websites homepage for foo.com .

Button 1: Continue in English (takes them to foo.com/english.html)

or

Button 2: Continue in Spanish (takes them to foo.com/spanish.html)

A checkbox would also be present, that if check would remember your choice and upon returning to foo.com you would go directly to english.html or spanish.html based on your previous selection.

I have never used cookies before, and having a hard time wrapping my head around how I would do this. The examples I have seen for cookies are basic, this seems more complex to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would probably be best accomplished on your web server instead of in Javascript. What backend are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of cookie libraries and jquery extentions available if you find it difficult dealing with them [discreetly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie), a G* search should return plenty.

A couple are:

[Cookies.js](https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies)
[jquery cookies](https://code.google.com/p/cookies/)

An alternative to cookies is to use [HTML5 localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: Thanks I am going to explore the HTML5 localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'm assuming you'd like to perform this task entirely from Javascript. The traditional method using [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie) can be tedious for those not proficient with Javascript. If you're already using jQuery, I recommend the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Either of which could be checked upon page initialization and a simple `if` statement performed to change the location of the browser window, effectively redirecting to a different page.